# How far does parody go in copyright laws in Canada?

Tags: copyright, canada, fair-use, parody

I'm wondering how far does parody go in Canadian copyright act? Is copying someone else's open source code and modifying it then protecting it considered as infringement?  The code is from a unregistered organisation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you don’t understand what [parody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parody) is. If you do understand, please explain how it’s even possible to parody computer code.

What you can do with “open source” code depends on the licence the copyright holder(s) release it under. For some very permissive licences you can do what you suggest, for most, you can’t.

Comment: What about programs without licenses?

Comment: You can’t use a program without a license at all

Comment: The license is what gives you permission to do _anything_. Without a license you can do nothing.

Comment: @gnasher729 unless the software is in the public domain.